# Get radar data from an image

Tags: php, image-processing

I have a problem..
There is some picture, like this:

[image]

and I want to add a new resolution, background, and better quality ( antialias) to this radar image. How can I get radar details from this image with a PHP script?

I have already this code, but the output isnt the best :S you can see it here:

[image]

```
<?
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('a.jpg');
$f1 = imagecolorallocate($im, 39, 78, 231); 
$a = imagecreatetruecolor ( 520, 370 );
$red = imagecolorallocate($a, 39,78,231); 
for($x =130;$x<520;$x++)
{
for($y = 130; $y<370;$y++)
{
    $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
    $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

    $red = imagecolorallocate($a, $r,$g,$b); 
    //echo $r.$     g.$b."|";

    if( ($r < 100 && $r > 0) && ($g < 150 && $g > 0) && ($b < 255 && $b > 150))
        imagesetpixel($a, $x, $y, $red);
    if( ($r < 100 && $r > 0) && ($g < 255 && $g > 130) && ($b < 255 && $b > 0))
        imagesetpixel($a, $x, $y, $red);
    if( ($r < 200 && $r > 100) && ($g < 255 && $g > 180) && ($b < 80 && $b > 0))
        imagesetpixel($a, $x, $y, $red);
    if( ($r < 255 && $r > 0) && ($g < 255 && $g > 0) && ($b < 50 && $b > 0))
        imagesetpixel($a, $x, $y, $red);
    if( ($r < 255 && $r > 200) && ($g < 255 && $g > 70) && ($b < 70 && $b > 0))
        imagesetpixel($a, $x, $y, $red);
    if( ($r < 255 && $r > 200) && ($g < 100 && $g > 0) && ($b < 70 && $b > 0))
        imagesetpixel($a, $x, $y, $red);
    if( ($r < 120 && $r > 0) && ($g < 50 && $g > 0) && ($b < 50 && $b > 0))
        imagesetpixel($a, $x, $y, $red);
}
} 
//$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 550, 465);
//$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
//$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
//$b = $rgb & 0xFF;
//echo "$r $g $b";
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($a);
?>
```

Comment: Nem is tudtam, hogy itt magyarok is vannak :D But anyway, the image you have, do you have a png quality version of it to process? Cuz then you could just get the colors from the map's key, and get those colors from the rest of the image, and copy them to your other background, but on a jpeg image, the colors aren't solid and because of the compression.

Comment: what do you mean for "radar details"?

Comment: `...with a PHP script` - that's a bad start. PHP is *not* a good language for this. And if you have no idea how to do this at all, then I'd suggest you basically give up now. What your are talking about is some very advance image manipulation, and a beginner (or even a not-so beginner) is going to struggle to extract any meaningful data from an image like that. If you must, I would say your best bet would be to attempt to [vectorise](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vectorise+image) it and lay the radar objects over another image.

Comment: dAm2K - Radar details are the colored fields, you see them blue, and green, yellow, and red in this picture.

19greg96 - én sem, ez az 1. kérdésem itt.. :D no, i have only this quality of image:S this provided by http://met.hu

Comment: Is the position of the radar-details box a standard? Do you need the corresponding names of the colors too (felhőszakadás - #460000 stb)? Or are those a constant across the images you have to process? Could we have a couple of other images please?

Comment: yeah. here is that: http://met.hu/idojaras/aktualis_idojaras/radar/

Comment: @19greg96 I shall be very interested to see where you are going with this... If you can come up with a works-every-time solution that is comprehensible I shall be mightily impressed ;-)

Comment: Well, if the map's key that has the colors is always on the same place than we could easily extract each color-code, create a new image, for-loop through the pixels of the old image and copy the colors that are the same (or round the colors and compare those because of the compression on the image) as the ones we got from the key. And I heard of existing php libs for extracting strings from images.

Comment: sry. updated the answer.

Comment: @19greg96 In theory the key box does not need to be in the same place, because due to the nature of the images (maps) there will never be another object that looks like it (4 straight edges inset in lighter colours) - but equally if you're going to take that approach then you don't need to care about the key box at all because the key colours and associated labels will most likely be common to all the images. But your ideas are sensible - just likely hard and inefficient to implement in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace kép.jpg with image. 1st try. I think I can adjust things to get closer.

2nd try: floor seems to be much better than round.

3rd try: added 2 filters to the code.

```
<?php
header('content-type: image/png');
//header('content-type: text/plain');


$im = imagecreatefromjpeg ('images/a.jpg');
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('images/a.jpg');

$im2 = imagecreate($width, $height);

$x = 540;
$y = 353;

$colors = array();


$num = 100;
$num2 = 15 * 11 * $num;
$num3 = 100;

$num4 = 65;
$num5 = 15 * 11 * $num4;
$num6 = 65;

imagecolorallocate($im2, 255, 255, 255);
for ($k = 0; $k < 7; $k ++) {
    $ar = 0;
    $ag = 0;
    $ab = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i ++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < 11; $j ++) {
            $tc = imagecolorat($im, $x + $i, $y + $j + $k * 18);
            $ar += ($tc >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $ag += ($tc >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $ab += $tc & 0xFF;
        }
    }

    $c = new STDClass();
    if ($k == 0) {
        $c->r = floor ($ar / $num5) * $num4;
        $c->g = floor ($ag / $num5) * $num4;
        $c->b = floor ($ab / $num5) * $num4;
    } else {
        $c->r = floor ($ar / $num2) * $num;
        $c->g = floor ($ag / $num2) * $num;
        $c->b = floor ($ab / $num2) * $num;
    }

    $c->c = imagecolorallocate($im2, $c->r, $c->g, $c->b);

    $colors[] = $c;

    imagefilledrectangle($im2, 0, $k * 11, 15, $k * 11 + 11, $c->c);
}


$pixelmap = array();
$pm2 = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $width; $i ++) {
    $pixelmap[$i] = array();
    $pm2[$i] = array();
    for ($j = 0; $j < $height; $j ++) {
        $pixelmap[$i][$j] = false;
        $pm2[$i][$j] = false;
        $c = imagecolorat($im, $i, $j);

        $r = ($c >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($c >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $c & 0xFF;

        $r = floor ($r / $num3) * $num3;
        $g = floor ($g / $num3) * $num3;
        $b = floor ($b / $num3) * $num3;

        $r2 = floor ($r / $num6) * $num6;
        $g2 = floor ($g / $num6) * $num6;
        $b2 = floor ($b / $num6) * $num6;


        for ($k = 0; $k < 7; $k ++) {
            $colorOK = true;
            if ($k == 0) {
                if ($r2 != $colors[$k]->r) { $colorOK = false; }
                if ($g2 != $colors[$k]->g) { $colorOK = false; }
                if ($b2 != $colors[$k]->b) { $colorOK = false; }
            } else {
                if ($r != $colors[$k]->r) { $colorOK = false; }
                if ($g != $colors[$k]->g) { $colorOK = false; }
                if ($b != $colors[$k]->b) { $colorOK = false; }
            }
            if ($colorOK) { break; }
        }


        if ($k < 7) { // else no mathing color was found
            $pixelmap[$i][$j] = $colors[$k]->c;
            //imagesetpixel($im2, $i, $j, $pixelmap[$i][$j]);
        }
    }
}


for ($i = 1; $i < $width - 1; $i ++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j < $height - 1; $j ++) {
        if ($pixelmap[$i][$j] !== false) {
            if ($pixelmap[$i    ][$j - 1] !== false ||
                $pixelmap[$i + 1][$j - 1] !== false ||
                $pixelmap[$i + 1][$j    ] !== false ||
                $pixelmap[$i + 1][$j + 1] !== false ||
                /*$pixelmap[$i  ][$j + 1] !== false ||*/
                $pixelmap[$i - 1][$j + 1] !== false ||
                $pixelmap[$i - 1][$j    ] !== false) {
                //imagesetpixel($im2, $i, $j, $pixelmap[$i][$j]);
            } else {
                $pixelmap[$i][$j] = false;
            }
            $pm2[$i][$j] = $pixelmap[$i][$j];
        } else {
            $surroundColors = array();
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j - 1]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j - 1]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j - 1]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i    ][$j - 1]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i    ][$j - 1]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i    ][$j - 1]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j - 1]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j - 1]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j - 1]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j    ]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j    ]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j    ]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j + 1]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j + 1]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j + 1]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i    ][$j + 1]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i    ][$j + 1]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i    ][$j + 1]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j + 1]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j + 1]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j + 1]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j    ]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j    ]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j    ]] = 1; };

            $c = array_keys ($surroundColors);
            $pm2[$i][$j] = ($c[0] == false ? false : $c[0]);
            //imagesetpixel($im2, $i, $j, $c[0]);
        }
    }
}

$pixelmap = $pm2;
for ($i = 1; $i < $width - 1; $i ++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j < $height - 1; $j ++) {
        if ($pixelmap[$i][$j] !== false) {
            if ($pixelmap[$i    ][$j - 1] !== false ||
                $pixelmap[$i + 1][$j - 1] !== false ||
                $pixelmap[$i + 1][$j    ] !== false ||
                $pixelmap[$i + 1][$j + 1] !== false ||
                /*$pixelmap[$i  ][$j + 1] !== false ||*/
                $pixelmap[$i - 1][$j + 1] !== false ||
                $pixelmap[$i - 1][$j    ] !== false) {
                imagesetpixel($im2, $i, $j, $pixelmap[$i][$j]);
            } else {
                $pixelmap[$i][$j] = false;
            }
        } else {
            $surroundColors = array();
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j - 1]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j - 1]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j - 1]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i    ][$j - 1]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i    ][$j - 1]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i    ][$j - 1]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j - 1]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j - 1]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j - 1]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j    ]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j    ]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j    ]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j + 1]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j + 1]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i + 1][$j + 1]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i    ][$j + 1]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i    ][$j + 1]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i    ][$j + 1]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j + 1]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j + 1]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j + 1]] = 1; };
            if (isset($surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j    ]])) { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j    ]]++; } else { $surroundColors[$pixelmap[$i - 1][$j    ]] = 1; };

            $c = array_keys ($surroundColors);
            //$pixelmap[$i][$j] = $c[0];
            imagesetpixel($im2, $i, $j, $c[0]);
        }
    }
}



imagepng ($im2);
?>
```

Comment: Nice work, thank you so much! :) i may have to do a bit smoother, and done :)

Comment: akartam, csak nem engedte, mert kiirt vmit :D

Comment: amugy nagyon faszányos már :)

Comment: köszi :D amúgy én eddig jutottam: http://i.imgur.com/nYzjy.png csak az a gond, hogy az első szín az túl sötét, és ha lejjebb viszem a határt akkor minden más sötét vonalat is belevesz.

Comment: azt kell csinálni, hogy ahol megegyezik a konvertált szín, ott az eredeti képröl szedi vissza a szineket.. probálgattam tegnap, de a térkép 5 % át rajzolta csak meg kb :S

Comment: nem értem, mit értesz konvertált szín alatt >.< de amm azt is lehetne, hogyha van egy üres mo. térképed, akkor egyszerűen kivonod a 2-t egymásból és megvan (szerintem, de lehet tévedek, megint csak a jpg tömörítés miatt)

Comment: hát ugye, te egy színt raksz rá azt a fura kéket, arra mondtam hogy konvertált szín. és ahelyett rátehetnéd az eredeti képen lévő azon a ponton lévő színt ^^:D

Comment: ja igen, azt is lehet, de úgy nem 'javulna' a minőség, ugyanis ottmaradna a jpg tömörítés, én egy szolid színt rakok a hasonlóak helyére :D

Comment: jaa stimm :DDD igen már értem :)